# No maximize button on XLib window

Tags: c++, window, xlib, maximize, disabled-control

Is it possible to create a window with **only Minimize and Close button** (and preferably not re-sizable) in C++ and XLib? 
On my Ubuntu I can see some of these type of windows (like the System Configuration window).

I am very new in the Linux+X11 world and I want to create a small window like this. How would this be done (not asking for code but for some references to the API components that would be of use or techniques that you know)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set _NET_WM_ACTION_MINIMIZE and _NET_WM_ACTION_RESIZE as the [list of allowed actions](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html#id2732155) for your window

Comment: Thanks. I have done it with `XChangeProperty()`, for those who may wonder